# Как нарисовать круговую диаграмму в HTML?

Tags: html, css, css3

Как нарисовать диаграмму поделенную на области в процентном соотношении? Не могу придумать как бы это реализовать, пробовал с помощью SVG, но потом нужно ее позиционировать и возникают сложности

Comment: Радиальным градиентом например

Comment: [вариант 1](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/dyoemQy) [вариант 2](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/QWjpzOw) [вариант 3](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/dyYRZrX) [это у кого то скомуниздил](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/pojqwRg)